# Overriding Bootstrap Nav Background-Color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to override the default Twitter Bootstrap Nav by having a main.css (see below) override the nav classes but changes are not being applied.

Here is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <style>
            body {
                padding-top: 60px;
                padding-bottom: 40px;
            }
        </style>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

        <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--[if lt IE 7]>
            <p class="chromeframe">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> or <a href="http://www.google.com/chromeframe/?redirect=true">activate Google Chrome Frame</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->

        <!-- This code is taken from http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/hero.html -->

        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="navbar-inner mynav">
                <div class="container">
                    <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="brand" href="#">Project name</a>
                    <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="nav">
                            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                    <li class="divider"></li>
                                    <li class="nav-header">Nav header</li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <form class="navbar-form pull-right">
                            <input class="span2" type="text" placeholder="Email">
                            <input class="span2" type="password" placeholder="Password">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign in</button>
                        </form>
                    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container">

            <!-- Main hero unit for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
            <div class="hero-unit">
                <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
                <p>This is a template for a simple marketing or informational website. It includes a large callout called the hero unit and three supporting pieces of content. Use it as a starting point to create something more unique.</p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
            </div>

            <!-- Example row of columns -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span4">
                    <h2>Heading</h2>
                    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
                    <p><a class="btn" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="span4">
                    <h2>Heading</h2>
                    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
                    <p><a class="btn" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>
               </div>
                <div class="span4">
                    <h2>Heading</h2>
                    <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
                    <p><a class="btn" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <hr>

            <footer>
                <p>&copy; Company 2012</p>
            </footer>

        </div> <!-- /container -->

        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

        <script src="js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <script src="js/main.js"></script>

        <script>
            var _gaq=[['_setAccount','UA-XXXXX-X'],['_trackPageview']];
            (function(d,t){var g=d.createElement(t),s=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
            g.src=('https:'==location.protocol?'//ssl':'//www')+'.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s)}(document,'script'));
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my main.css (notice main.css is loaded after the bootstrap CSS):

```
/* ==========================================================================
   My custom styles
   ========================================================================== */

.navbar-inverse .navbar-inner{
    background-color:#1f5b73;
}
```

That background color shows up on the Chrome dev tool as the current property being used and all other background properties seem to have been overwritten but I still don't see the change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the background is actually a linear-gradient, not a colour.  Use the `none` value for the `background-image` property and *then* specify the background-color. You can also see from my fiddle that its not a specificity issue:

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-inner {
background-image: none;
background-color: #1f5b73;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/5290/

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you're using bootstrap (I use rails), you can customize the colors with the less variables listed on the customize section of the twitter [Bootstrap Website](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/customize.html).

Example:

@navbarBackground: #222;

@navbarBackgroundHighlight: #999;